# How to consume wcf rest in windows store app

Tags: windows-store-apps

I am consuming wcf rest service that is hosted on windows azure service link http://winrttest.cloudapp.net/

while I am creating object for service client's constructor with two parameters that I saw in reference.cs file in windows store app, but actually in service app the service class's constructor is not parameterized.
  Reference.cs:

public Service1Client(System.ServiceModel.Channels.Binding binding, System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress remoteAddress) : 
                base(binding, remoteAddress)
{
        }

Am trying to pass those two parameters ,but am unable to pass binding as webhttpbinding.
how can I create instance for serviceclient class.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is normal. 
You cannot consume a wcf rest service like a "normal" wcf service by adding the service reference and so on. You can use your rest service through HttpClient.

[Have a look here for details](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/03/26/mixing-add-service-reference-and-wcf-web-http-a-k-a-rest-endpoint-does-not-work.aspx)